# Do Shell Substitutions in String

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string in memory, assigned to a bash variable, which has placeholders in it. I want to perform replacements of those using variables in the environment.

For example

```sh
#!/bin/bash
MYSTRING='Hello, ${FOO}'
export FOO="world!"
REPLACED=$(how?${MYSTRING})
echo "${REPLACED}"
# should return Hello, world!
```

What I need is this part `$(how?${MYSTRING})`

(I am the only person who will use this script and there are no opportunities for bad actors to inject malicious code.)

Comment: See the pattern replacement operator in [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#targetText=The%20parameter%20is%20a%20shell,as%20part%20of%20its%20name.)

Comment: in the first line `${FOO}` will evaluate to empty string if it's not already set by export.

Comment: @XBlueCode No, because it's a single quoted string it'll be a literal `${FOO}`.

Comment: When you feel the need to use this pattern,  99.9999% of the time it's a bad design. I suggest you rethink your approach. `REPLACED=$(eval "echo $MYSTRING")`, would work for the 1 in a million cases when you would really need it.

Comment: @Sorin, that doesn't seem to work because $MYSTRING is not a bash script.

Comment: @MatthewJamesBriggs, that's why you have a echo in front of $MYSTRING

Comment: Why are you using `export`?  To assign a variable, just write `FOO='world!'`.  (Better to use lower case names and write `foo='world!'`, but that's another discussion.) . Unless you actually need to export the variable, there's no reason to do so.  It will confuse your maintainers (you 2 years in the future, perhaps) who will wonder why its being exported.

Comment: `MYSTRING='Hello, ${FOO}'; bar="world!"; echo ${MYSTRING/\$\{FOO\}/$bar}`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `envsubst` from the gettext tools.

> You would be able to use `eval` but you **risk executing unwanted statements** from your string.

At least, `envsubst` will only expand environment variables to their values, and that's it, nothing else, no command evaluation, not even string substitutions...

See: https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
MYSTRING=$'Hello, ${FOO}'
FOO="world!"
REPLACED="$(
  # envsubst needs variables exported to its environment.
  # since this is a sub-shell, the environment scope
  # is this sub-shell.
  # It helps dealing with local variables that you would not want
  # to export to the environment for the main shell.
  # FOO's value is inherited from parent shell,
  # and exported to to this sub-shell's environment.
  export FOO  
  # pass MYSTRING as stdin here-string to envsubst
  envsubst <<<"$MYSTRING"
)"
echo "${REPLACED}"
```

Note that this will work only with simple variables, no arrays.
Variables need to be exported to work with `envsubst`

Now as said above, with great cautions, this can be done with `eval`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

MYSTRING='Hello, ${FOO}$(echo "eval is evil" >/tmp/pawned.txt)'
FOO="world!"
eval "REPLACED=\"${MYSTRING}\""
echo "${REPLACED}"
```

At first glance the output is looking legit:

```
Hello, world!
```

But look at `cat /tmp/pawned.txt`

```
eval is evil
```